# Detect when a user clears notification from the notification center

Tags: objective-c, ios

My app needs to know if a user deletes/clears the apps notifications from the notification center using the clear button.

Is there either away to detect when the user removes the notification from the notification center or grab an array of notification on the notification center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You (ie App) cannot interact with NotificationCenter, NotificationCenter interacts with the user.  A user can choose not to receive any push-notifications.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: So it doesn't inform the app that a notification it created has been cleared?

Comment: No, it doesn't even tell you if a push-notification got received or not. It's fire and forget. How would it even tell your app anything if it's not running.